# Is there a command specifically designed to manipulate file path strings, such as changing foo/bar/baz -> bar/baz?

Tags: command-line, filenames, string

I'm trying to modify the output of `git diff --name-only` from a subdirectory of a git project such that it only contains relative paths in the current directory. I know how to do this with `sed`/`grep`, but I was wondering if there are any cli commands specifically designed to manipulate file path strings in the following ways:

1. remove *n* parts from the beginning of a path:

   > `/foo/bar/baz` -> `bar/baz`
2. remove *n* parts from the end of a path:

   > `/foo/bar/baz` -> `/foo/bar/`
3. compare two paths and create a path relative to the current one:

   > `foo/bar/baz` relative to `foo/qux` -> `../bar/baz`
4. (optionally) strip all but the last part from the path (`basename` does this):

   > `/foo/bar/baz.ex`->`baz.ex`
5. (optionally) strip just the last part from the path (`dirname` does this):

   > `foo/…/bar/baz.ex` ->`foo/…/bar/`

Comment: I don't understand. If you know how to do this with `sed`, what else do you need? And where would these paths be? Stored in a shell variable (if so, you can use the shell's string manipulation features)? Stored in a file (then `sed` is the way to go)?

Comment: @terdon `sed`, being line oriented, would not be able to handle all possible filenames (and it would be slow). A parameter substitution would, though.

Comment: @Kusalananda if they are stored in a file, which is where I suggested `sed`, then sed will be able to deal with them since there will either be no newlines or there will be some other way of showing where one file ends and the other begins. And sed can be replaced by any other tool like ed or perl etc. Probably even split and cut. But we need to know where the OP will have the paths first.

Comment: @terdon: `sed` syntax can get complex if you need to handle edge cases. a specialized tool would make it simpler to do this. Also note that the example I gave was to illustrate one use case for such a tool, and is not the actual question.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner I get that, but in order to be able to think of tools, we still need to know where those paths will be stored. Do you want a tool whose input are strings (including variables) or files (a list of paths)?

Comment: @terdon I would say assume the paths could come from any source (a file, command argument, stdin, etc.), and that the files they refer to don't necessarily exist (they probably do, but it would be better if they don't have to).

Comment: @terdon I was hoping there would be a command like `filenamemanip --operation --arg1 filename1 filename2 …` and ideally it would work like a filter as well (according to the unix philosophy), taking std in for its arguments (but not options)

Comment: (1) and (2) can be done really easily with `awk -F/`.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner ah, OK, that's different. I thought you wanted it to also be able to open a file and read a list of paths from that file. Either way though, I don't think anything like this exists. The only non-trivial of these is 3 since that can't be done by text parsing and will require reading the file system (since there can be multiple `foo` directories, so you can't build the relative path without knowing about the filesystem).

Comment: @GarrettMotzner The main issue with using `sed` or `awk` or any line-oriented tool is that newlines in pathnames would be difficult to detect and handle correctly. If the pathnames are stored in a _file_, one almost have to assume that none of them contain any newlines. If they are stored in _variables_ or are given on a command line (e.g. from a glob expansion), they could potentially contain newlines if such names exists. A _generic_ tool for handling pathnames would _have to_ care about all possible allowed pathnames, not just names containing characters that are commonly used.

Comment: @Kusalananda Good point. Some tools (like `find` and `cpio`) have an option that treats a null byte as the separator, instead of the newline. So while it is a concern, it has a known solution.